# e(...).find(...).addBack is not a function Kendo Grid SetOptions

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Grid with a button that take you to other view where all the data of the item selected is show, what I'm trying to do is that when the user return to the grid view, the filters of the grid remain instead of show all the data.

For saving the filters, I use the `getOptions` method of Kendo Grid and stored on `localStorage` using the following code:

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
var op = grid.getOptions();
localStorage["KendoGridOptions"] = JSON.stringify(op);
```

And get this:

[image: object in console]

The problem is when I try to use the `setOptions` method, I do this on `$(document).ready` after initialize the grid:

```
var options = localStorage["KendoGridOptions"];
if (options) {
    var op = JSON.parse(options);
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.setOptions({
        dataSource: op.dataSource
    });
    localStorage.removeItem("KendoGridOptions");
}
```

And I get this error on the `gid.setOptions` line:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to resolve that error or how to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was the jQuery version, `addBack` function is added on the 1.8 version, this project still have the 1.7, just change the version and works perfect.

Comment: You're the best, this saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved by below method. If you want only page number, page size, sort and filter mention only those. I tried saving all the options and i remember having issues. I have spent lot of time on this. Let me know if you still have any issues

```
function saveGridOptions() {
var grid = $("#gridName").data("kendoGrid");
var dataSource = grid.dataSource;

var state = {
    page: dataSource.page(),
    pageSize: dataSource.pageSize(),
    sort: dataSource.sort(),
    filter: dataSource.filter()
};
    localStorage["kendo-grid-options"] = kendo.stringify(state);    
}


function loadGridOptions() {
var grid = $("#gridName").data("kendoGrid");
var state = "";   
state = localStorage["kendo-grid-options"];

if (state) {

    data = JSON.parse(state);
    var options = grid.options;
    options.dataSource.page = data.page;
    options.dataSource.pageSize = data.pageSize;
    options.dataSource.sort = data.sort;
    options.dataSource.filter = data.filter;
    grid.destroy();

    $("#gridName")
   .kendoGrid(options);

}
```

}

Comment: I tried to use your code, but still have the same error, now on the `grid.destroy()` line,  any idea?

Comment: The problem was the jQuery version, `addBack` function is added on the 1.8 version, this project still have the 1.7, just change the version and works perfect.